# Update css in old project with jeet 2

Tags: css-frameworks

I have this project I worked on with jeet 2, and that I need to update some styles.

In my machine I updated already the jeet version to version 3 via npm

Now when I do "jeet watch" I got this error :

```
Doesn't appear to be a Jeet Directory
```

I tried using Prepros to watch and compile the .styl files but I got another error :

```
> 1| @import 'nib'
  2| 
  3| /*  Syntax quick reference
  4|  *  ----------------------

failed to locate @import file nib.styl
```

Any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeet's major releases really don't have a good way to elegantly upgrade as they're so drastically different from the last.

For instance, Jeet isn't a command line tool anymore. But you can use it as a Stylus library: https://github.com/mojotech/jeet#installation

So far as nib failing to be found it's probably not on your system. Try this: `npm install -g nib`

Comment: It worked !! so if anyone got the same problem juste install nib globally and check in ur preprocessor that its using nib. Thank you very much =)